# Create Shortcut to Open File with Portable App

Tags: windows, shortcuts, portable, portable-apps

I recently figured out that I could import a Windows shortcut link to Calibre as a "book" and have it open whatever I want in its own default program.  I was thrilled to figure that out, but as I am also in the process of going purely Portable, I now have the trouble of trying to figure out how to make a shortcut that links not just the file, but also the Portable App I want to use to open it.  I've searched extensively, and I've just about come to the conclusion that it's not possible.  At least, not using Windows-typical options.

What I want is a shortcut to my file K:/Stills/Favorites/Fave1.jpg that also calls K:/Portable/IrfanviewPortable/Irfanview.exe to open it.  If it has to be the other way around, linking to the program and then telling it where the file is to open, that would work, too, as long as it can be adapted to other programs and formats.  I have video and audio files I would like to link, as well.

I've found several "how to" that explain making a shortcut to a URL using a specific browser, but I don't see a way to convert that to what I'm trying to do.  I've seen a few discussions of shortcuts to batch files, which seems like it may be the only way to make this work, but I don't know enough to convert what they're discussing into what I would need.

I'm not a coder, but I can understand if you explain like you would to a freshman coding class.  I passed C programming (barely) but that was 20something years ago.

Comment: Where will this shortcut be stored? You could use relative paths in your shortcut.

Comment: I was planning to put it in my Calibre Portable, which, yes, would be on the same external drive.  I don't know anything about making Windows shortcuts with relative paths, though?